# JSF 2 value not getting parsed in XHTML

Tags: maven, jsf

I am new to JSF 2 and trying to build simple hello world app.Created maven project in Eclipse Luna with maven-archetype-webapp. 
Following is my files :

1. **web.xml** :

> ```
>  <servlet>
>     <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
>     <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
>     <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
>     </servlet>  
> <servlet-mapping>
>     <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
>     <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
> </servlet-mapping>
> ```

2. **HelloWorld.java** :

   ```
   @ManagedBean(name = "helloWorld", eager = true) 
       public class HelloWorld {
   public HelloWorld() { 
   System.out.println("HelloWorld started!"); 
   } public String getMessage() { 
        return "Hello World!"; 
   }
   ```
3. **home.xhtml** :

   ```
   <body>

   <h1>HI....!!!</h1> 
       #{helloWorld.message}
       <h:outputLabel value="#{helloWorld.message}" />
   <h1>END....!!!</h1> 
   </body> 
   </html>
   ```

   When i run, my home.xhtml prints HI....!!! and END...!!!,but nothing else.

I have searched in SO and googled. I found solutions but unfortunately, i am unable to solve it.

Comment: *I have searched in SO and googled. I found solutions but unfortunately, i am unable to solve it.* to solve what? I cannot read what's your specific issue with this.

Comment: @mprabhat it's getter only.

Comment: @mprabhat I have tried adding String message in the bean.Got, the same result.

Comment: You have not defined any scope and I believe your ManagedBean is being instantiated and managed by JSF runtime. In that case your scope will be NoneScoped. Try adding @RequestScoped to your managedbean. NoneScoped can only be called by Another ManagedBean and not by UI. Also you can remove the eager attribute

Answer (score 0):

Some explanations on your current code:

- `@ManagedBean` defines a managed bean to be used in Facelets by JSF. The attribute `eager` only applies for `@ApplicationScoped` beans, and your managed bean doesn't have such scope.
- In JSF 2, if you don't define a scope for your bean, then it's `@RequestScoped` by default.
- Looks like your html doesn't use any Facelets code. This is how your home.xhtml should be:

  ```
  <!-- HTML5 header -->
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <!-- define f: and h: usage in the current page -->
  <html lang="en"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
  <!-- JSF will include some js files for ajax functionality -->
      <h:head>
          <!-- this is optional -->
          <title>Home</title>
      </h:head>
  <!-- use <h:body> for the content of your page -->
      <h:body>
          <h1>HI....!!!</h1> 
          #{helloWorld.message}
          <!--
              <h:outputLabel> will render a <label> and
              this component should not be used to print
              direct text on html but to label other HTML components
              instead, use <h:outputText>
          -->
          <h:outputText value="#{helloWorld.message}" />
          <h1>END....!!!</h1>
      </h:body>
  </html>
  ```

Comment: Thanks..i tried adding scope and removing eager. Also, made changes in xhtml file, but i get the same earlier result.

Comment: @coolmego how are you accessing to your page in your web browser?

Comment: Does `HelloWorld started!` gets printed in your app server log file?

Comment: Apologies...i am using jetty(plugin for Luna)...can not find the SOP being printed in the console.Unsure, where to find the log file.

Comment: :No, the SOP does not print "HelloWorld started!" in the log file.